# We are in 2200 and global warming hits us very bad. Can we create a winter?

Tags: climate-change

Let's assume a society similar to ours, a few hundreds of years in the future. We managed to trigger a snowball effect on global warming with our fossil fuel use. Earth is very hot. The technology is not much different from what we have now, unfortunately.

We know that some dramatic events, such as volcanic eruptions or a nuclear war can reduce the global temperature. Can we artificially trigger a winter? It should last for hopefully a few years and, most important, be safe for humans.

Further clarifications: by society similar to us, I mean with the same technological level and same geo-political issues. Another view of my question would be "if the global warming gets really bad soon, can we get away with an artificial winter?". The future was chosen for the impact of the climate change, I assume a society similar to ours in all aspects.

Comment: So, your question is in the close queue on account of it not being about [worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) per se.  Since you're proposing a futuristic world, you have 200 years of explaining to do. "Society like ours" is meaningless in the context of time. Consider what society, technology, & scientific advancement  in any country were like 200 years ago vs today. You get the point. These are things you need to spell out in order for your question to be even marginally answered.

Comment: The trick of this is to be creative.  On this site there are dozens of scheme from the practical (increase albedo, fertilize oceans) to outre (increase the earths orbital diameter, cool the sun).  For an interesting fiction you need to give your world tech or an approach that we don't have, and a method so far undreamt of.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you gave, volcanoes and nuclear war, cause a winter because of particles that are ejected into the atmosphere, blocking the sun and causing a winter. Therefore, a solution could be to just spray dust into the sky, as your society presumably has superior technology.

This, however, would cause most plants to die out, and unless humans have prepared for this, it would be catastrophic. Additionally, the dust may trigger nasty things like asthma and dust pneumonia. This, obviously, isn't a good thing. Another thing that comes to mind is moving the planet away from the star, but your society doesn't have the tech, so that's off the table.

Currently, it is possible to seed clouds, and with a few advancements, you could *maybe* get to the result you want. You could also plant a lot of really prolific trees, causing them to spread wildly, taking up CO2 in the process. They're not perfect solutions, but they could work.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: There actually is an ongoing research project to spray dust into the upper atmosphere for cooling purposes.  https://spectrum.ieee.org/solar-geoengineering